# How can I specify ServiceAccount to be picked up by config.load_incluster_config() from kubernetes python sdk

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-python-client

I have an environment with multiple ServiceAccounts, and pod with access to Kubernetes api using kubernetes python sdk. Which account does the function load_incluster_config() pick up. Is there any way I can specify an account to be picked?
I have seen my pod to always pick the "default" named ServiceAccount.

Answer (score 6):

As per the code [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python-base/blob/master/config/incluster_config.py) it picks up the token from `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` path inside the pod. So what you need to do is just have a different service account in the pod spec

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: build-robot
```

Then it will pick up the service account `build-robot`. Also note you need to configure role and rolebinding for this service account.